# IIS using (URL Rewrite) to Redirect to another domain

Tags: url, iis, iis-10

trying to redirect from `https://www.domain.info/cms-cp/login.html` to `https://www-server2.domain.info/cms-cp/login.html`
by using the following code for (URL Rewrite) plugin, but unfortunately not working.

```
<rule name="Redirect To Web2 Server CMS"  enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^(www.domain.info/cms-cp/login.html)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www-server2.domain.info/cms-cp/login.html" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
</rule>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? Please describe what happens and what you expect to happen instead.

Comment: it didn't even redirect to anything

Comment: I was expecting redirect to `https://www-server2.domain.info/cms-cp/login.html`

Comment: Don't know from where you learned URL rewriting, but `HTTPS` never matches that invalid pattern. You can see what it carries by enabling FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Domain name and path should be checked by HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<rule name="Redirect To Server2" patternSyntax="ECMAScript"  enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">  
    <match url="login.html" />
    <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.domain\.info$" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www-server2.domain.info/cms-cp/login.html" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: A minimum of explanation would be nice...

Answer (score 0):

{HTTPS} is just a bool value to check whether https has been enabled or not.
So you can apply the rule just like this

```
<rule name="Redirect To Web2 Server CMS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^on$" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www\.domain\.info" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/cms-cp/login.html$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www-server2.domain.info/cms-cp/login.html" />
                </rule>
```